# NodeJS Net module doesn't send message to server

Tags: node.js, delphi

I am using NodeJS [Net module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/net) to send a TCP message to a server.

I studied some code on the internet and end up with this simple code:

```
var enviarMensagemTCP = function (mensagem, port, host) {
  const Net = require("net");

  const client = Net.createConnection({ port: port, host: host });

  console.log(`enviar mensagem TCP para ${host}:${port}`);
  client.on("connect", function () {
    client.write(`${mensagem}`, () => {
      client.destroy();
    });
  });

  client.on("error", function (error) {
    client.destroy();
  });
};
```

My client is successfully connection to the server, however no message is read by the server I wrote in delphi.

```
    IDPessoa := AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadLn;
```

Comment: How the heck did you ask and answer a question at the same time?

Comment: I was struggling with the problem for about three days and looking for the answer on the internet, after some time I figured it out by myself and decided to share, in case someone end up in the same situation.

Comment: Ohh I see. I think the proper etiquette here would be to phrase the question more as a _request for comment_ rather than as an actual question, being as you already knew the answer. [Check this out.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17847/1032701)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was simple, I was trying to read the line in the server, however, my client was not sending the data line by line.

Just added a line breaking after the message fixed the issue.

```
client.write(`${mensagem}\r\n`, () => {
      client.destroy();
    });
```